# who wakes up a process which is blocked because it executed wait on a semaphore unsuccessfully?

Tags: synchronization, operating-system, scheduling, semaphore

If a process executes a wait on a semaphore and is unsuccesful(since the value of the semaphore was initially 0), I understand that the process is blocked(goes to sleep mode?). Who wakes the process up when the semaphore value is greater than 0?
Is this operating system specific? If yes, then how do POSIX semaphores behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine this is OS-specific but don't see many ways of doing it.

For example on Linux doing an `up` on a semaphore wakes up the waiting tasks (look up wait queues) and marks them runnable. The scheduler then decides which task to run if any.

Comment: Is this true with POSIX semaphores?

Comment: thanks for the reply but this is not homework question. I checked it on windows. The process which does **up** makes the sleeping process runnable. I want to make sure if the process does not busy wait when the semaphore value is 0.

Comment: @ajaybidari No. A general property of semaphores is that they don't do busy waiting. That's what spinlocks do.

Answer (score 0):

When a semaphore is released, the related threads are removed from block, but the scheduler is not necessarily run.  So, the behavior is undefined.

Looking at the semaphore code should provide an answer.

Running a simple multi-thread test can provide a practical answer.  One thread has a loop that takes the sempanore and sets the variable to 1 and then releases the variable and sets the variable to zero. The other thread in a loop takes the semaphore and prints the variable, twice and releases the semaphore.

If the schedule is run when the semaphore is released, the other thread will run immediately, if not the original thread will run until until it blocks on the semaphore.

On my machine the pattern of ones and zeros was erratic.
Adding usleep() after the semaphore release will encourage the scheduler to run.
Adding in the sleep made it fairly stable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *functionCount1();
void *functionCount2();

int  x = 0;

void main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;

   pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionCount1, NULL);
   pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionCount2, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   exit(0);
}

void *functionCount1()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
        x = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );
        // usleep(10);
        x = 1;
    }
}

void *functionCount2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
        printf("%d", x);
        // usleep(10);
        printf("%d", x);
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );
    }
}
```