# Who manages Mutexes and friends?

Tags: synchronization, operating-system

Are mutexes, semaphores, events, etc. considered a part of the OS kernel, or are they a separate user-level library that is just usually supplied with the OS?

Does calling an operation on a semaphore involve a system call (interrupt/trap/ring-0)?

In theory, could I write a user-level synchronization/locking library (not thread management, just syncing/locking!) that would not call the OS functions behind the scenes?

If I was to write a multi-threaded OS kernel, would I have to include things like create/release/grab semaphore, or would I be able to just ship with an existing library compiled for my OS?

---

As you can see, I am a little confused on this subject. These are all basically the same question in different formats.

I am interested in an OS theory answer, as well as "This is how it is done in Linux/Windows/Some other *nix" answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad and depend on the OS. You should look at the following Question: [Mutex access and system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067982/mutex-access-and-system-call?rq=1), [who wakes up a process which is blocked because it executed wait on a semaphore unsuccessfully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409988/who-wakes-up-a-process-which-is-blocked-because-it-executed-wait-on-a-semaphore?rq=1)

Basically one try to avoid system call using compare and swap and fall back to system call to put the thread asleep.